# It is possible to install Salesforce cli through command line?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-cli

I am in the process of build automation for Salesforce, as a requirement I need to install "Salesforce CLI" and execute few commands.
I went through the [chocolaty commands](https://chocolatey.org/packages/sfdx-cli), but it doesn't seems to be working, is there any other way around to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal SFDX CLI installer: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm

If you use Chocolatey and `choco install sfdx-cli` throws you some errors - usually the info what to do about the error is right there in the message.

> Error -
>   hashes do not match. Actual value was
>   '947036CB8228616B0C9A94B9F11FD43225188C1839A7475930288CA650B78361'.
>   ERROR: Checksum for
>   'C:\Users[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\sfdx-cli\6.0.16\sfdx-windows-amd64.exe'
>   did not meet
>   '9C33344AED91F6CC2CF97A64A69D99CBAD9EBBF4A28920B8160CDFCE83772326' for
>   checksum type 'sha256'. **Consider passing the actual checksums through
>   with --checksum --checksum64 once you validate the checksums are
>   appropriate. A less secure option is to pass --ignore-checksums if
>   necessary.** The install of sfdx-cli was NOT successful.

`choco install sfdx-cli --ignore-checksums` should work OK.

Next error you might get will be about typos in the install script (author of choco package didn't escape spaces properly and it dies on "C:\Program Files", at least on my machine):

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. ERROR: Running ["cmd" /C "C:\Program
>   Files\sfdx\bin\sfdx.exe" update] was not successful. Exit code was
>   '1'. See log for possible error

We can have a look at what's in the install script, failed installations typically are copied to "lib-bad": `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib-bad\sfdx-cli\tools`

I'm not a PowerShell guru but by the look of it it just tries to run `sfdx update` at the end of installation. I can skip the script and run it manually.

`choco install sfdx-cli --ignore-checksums -n` works OK
and then close the console (to reload the PATH variables). Open new console and 
`sfdx update` will work too.

> sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 7.54.4-8ff9ba9cc5

Answer (score 0):

Try to download *Node.js* via chocolatey:

`cinst nodejs.install`

and then use *[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)* (gets installed with *Node.js*) to download the [Salesforce-CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdx-cli):

`npm install --global sfdx-cli`

Answer (score 0):

Install Node JS

curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash -
yum -y install nodejs
npm install -g npm

**Install latest sfdx cli**

npm install --global sfdx-cli

**Install specific version of sfdx cli**

npm install --global sfdx-cli@[version]

**Uninstall**

npm uninstall --global sfdx-cli